# Rails: Can't use collection outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a **Rails 6** application on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

Right now I am trying to define an `import` route under the `products` resources.

Below is my **routes** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products 
    collection do
      post :import
    end
end
```

However, when I start my Rails server, I get the error below:

```
`collection': can't use collection outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)
```

Still trying to figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix for it.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I was supposed to wrap the `import` route collection in a block under the `products` resources.

So instead of this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
    collection do
      post :import
    end
end
```

It should be this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products do
    collection do
      post :import
    end
  end
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**